# How do I delete rows by condition with data from different table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table1:

```
ID month  first_name last_name
11  1       bla1       bla2
11  2       bla1       bla2
11  3       bla1       bla2
11  4       bla1       bla2
22  1       bla3       bla4
22  2       bla3       bla4
22  3       bla3       bla4
22  4       bla3       bla4
```

And another table - table2:

```
Id month
11  1
11  3 
22  4
```

And I want to delete the records from table 1 according to table 2 so I end up with:

```
ID month  first_name last_name

    11  2       bla1       bla2
    11  4       bla1       bla2
    22  1       bla3       bla4
    22  2       bla3       bla4
    22  3       bla3       bla4
```

Any simple way to do that?

```
Delete from table1 tb1
where tb1.Id = tb2.Id and tb1.month  = tb2.month
```

but I'm sure about the correct join.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this to specify what data to delete when doing a join.

```
DELETE tb1
FROM table1 as tb1
INNER JOIN table2 as tb2 ON tb1.Id = tb2.Id
WHERE tb1.month = tb2.month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete tb1 
from table1 tb1
where exists
         (select 1 from table2 
           where tb1.id=tb2.id 
          and tb1.month=tb2=month)
```